# Tried to get janitor and got the message for dpkg dependency problem on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dpkg

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of computer-janitor-gtk:
 computer-janitor-gtk depends on computer-janitor (= 2.1.0-0ubuntu8); however:
  Package computer-janitor is not installed.
dpkg: error processing computer-janitor-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Answer (score 1):

Computer Janitor is available in Ubuntu apps.  To install click [**Computer Janitor** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/computer-janitor-gtk/)

This is the GNOME version.